# Piping stdin and stdout

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin

My goal is to create a child process that gets plugged between the parent process stdin and stdout using pipes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

int main(){
    int fd1[2], fd2[2];
    pid_t pid;

    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);
    
    pid = fork();

    if(pid > 0){
        printf("stdin to fd1 write\n");
        dup2(fd1[WRITE], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd1[READ]);
        printf("stdout to fd2 read\n");
        dup2(fd2[READ], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd2[WRITE]);
    }
    else{
        printf("stdin to fd1 read\n");
        dup2(fd1[READ], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        printf("stdout to fd2 write\n");
        dup2(fd2[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd2[READ]);
        printf("there\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

I'm aware the code is very unsafe, but this is a test environment so I didn't bother putting in the usual safeguards - I know, I know, the point was zooming in on the pipe thing, the implementation target already has the safeguards in place.

This is my output:

```
stdin to fd1 write
stdout to fd2 read
stdin to fd1 read
stdout to fd2 write
```

Which means the piping isn't happening at all. How could I go about this? From where I'm standing the logic is correct: parent stdin to write end of pipe 1, child stdin to read end of pipe 1, child stdout to write end of pipe 2, parent stdout to read end of pipe 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The parent doesn't need to use `dup2()`. It should copy its standard input to one of the pipes, and copy from the other pipe to its standard output.

Comment: This is most easily done using multiple threads in the parent. One thread for copying stdin to the child, the other thread for copying from the child to stdout. Otherwise you can get deadlock.

Comment: the base implementation is done like that - parent reads from stdin, sends to child, child sends back parent writes it to stdout. however I was told there was a way to make this happen without storing the contents of the pipe in memory, and I took that as a challenge

Comment: regarding deadlock, current implementation is using waitpid to ensure the child is done before the parent copies to stdout

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: It also isn't 100% clear what you're trying to do.  Is the child writing to the parent's standard input and the parent is then reading that and writing to its standard output?  If so, you don't need two pipes; one is sufficient.  If the parent's standard output is to go back to the child, then you do need to read the data — and there is no data being read anywhere.

Comment: @PedroBarbeira There isn't a way to directly connect two different streams. Normally what happens is that the child simply inherits its parent's stdXXX streams, so no pipes are needed at all. You only need pipes if you want to communicate between the processes.